# JPQL @Query for a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

Please I need some help. I've got 2 entities:

**Appointment.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "appointment")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Appointment {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    private Date modifiedDate;
    
    @Column(name = "appointment_date")
    private LocalDate appointmentDate;
    
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalTime startTime;
    
    private Boolean cancelled;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "client_id")
    private Client clientId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee; 
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "service_id")
    private Service service;
}
```

And **Employee.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @Column(name = " modified_date")
    private Date modifiedDate;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Service service; 
}
```

I need to get all the appointments that match with the given `startTime`, `appointmentDate` and `employee`
I want to define an abstract method in the interface `AppointmentRepo` so that in my `AppointmentServices.class` I can call that method with 3 arguments and get the appointment entity.

AppointmentServices.class

```
appointmentRepo.getAppointmentByDateAndEmployee(date, employee, scheduledHour);
```

**AppointmentRepo interface**

```
@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepo extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Integer>{
    
    @Query("SELECT a FROM Appointment a INNER JOIN a.employee e WHERE a.appointmentDate = :appointment_date AND e = :employee AND s.startTime = :start_time")
    public List<Appointment> getAppointmentByDateAndEmployee (@Param("appointment_date") LocalDate appointmentDate, 
            @Param("employee_id") Employee employee, @Param("start_time") LocalTime startTime); 

}
```

How I have to set my @Query in order to be given an appointment entity that matches with 3 given arguments (a date, and time and a reference to other entity called Employee)
Am I doing wrong matching the entire object so I need just to use the id of the Employee entity?

Please help me, and thanks for your time!!
Happy Holidays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL instead HQL (nativeQuery=true)

**DAO Layer**

```
package com.jb.app.repos;

import com.jb.app.beans.Appointment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM APPOINTMENT WHERE appointment_date = ?1 AND start_time = ?2 AND employee_id = ?3", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Appointment> getAppointmentByDateAndEmployee(LocalDate appointmentDate, LocalTime startTime, int employeeId);

}
```

**Service Layer**

```
package com.jb.app.services;

import com.jb.app.beans.Appointment;
import com.jb.app.beans.Employee;
import com.jb.app.repos.AppointmentRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.List;


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppointmentServiceImpl implements AppointmentService{
    
    private final AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;
    
    @Override
    public List<Appointment> getAppointmentByDateAndEmployee(LocalDate appointmentDate, LocalTime startTime, Employee e) {
        return appointmentRepository.getAppointmentByDateAndEmployee(appointmentDate,startTime,e.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote your response but I cannot because my reputation ain't enough xD. Cheers!